C# Method call not recognising parameters (CS0103)
I had to make a small program for a project and I made a quiz game that takes a user score at the end.
I did this by having multiple objects for the questions which are then called to be printed by a method, then multiple individual methods take the user's input, validate the answer and then either add or subtract points if the user's answer is correct.
Here is the code for this part/file:
namespace Quiz_for_bootcamp_project_1
{
    public class QuestionSheet
    {
       public string questions;
        public string answers;

        public QuestionSheet(string questions, string answers) 
        { 
        this.questions = questions;
        this.answers = answers;
        }

        public QuestionSheet Q1 = new QuestionSheet("What's 2+2?", "4");
        public QuestionSheet Q2 = new QuestionSheet("What's 5X3?", "15");
        public QuestionSheet Q3 = new QuestionSheet("What fruit is orange and round?", "ORANGE");
        public QuestionSheet Q4 = new QuestionSheet("What animal barks?", "DOG");
        public QuestionSheet Q5 = new QuestionSheet("What is the name of the IDE that this program was written in?", "C#");
    }

    public class AnswerMethods() 
    {
        public String uAInput = Console.ReadLine();
        public static int userHighScore = 0;

        public static string UserAnswerIput() 
        { 
            String uAInput =Console.ReadLine();
    
            return uAInput;
        }

        public static string AnswerValidator(String uAInput, string answers)
        {
            if (uAInput == answers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Correct! 10 points for you!");
                AddPoints(userHighScore);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect! -10 points.");
                RemovePoints(userHighScore);
            }
            return UserAnswerIput();
        }

        public static int AddPoints(int userHighScore)
        {
            int finalScore = userHighScore + 10;
            return finalScore;
        }

        public static int RemovePoints(int userHighScore)
        {
            int finalScore = userHighScore - 10;
            return finalScore;
        }
    }
}

(additionally the reason I used classes instead of something simpler was because for the project I had to try and utilise everything I'd learned about C# so far)
After this I created another file/class with methods that start the game, end the game and call the questions (additionally, the end of each question method will call the next question method with the last question method calling the "EndGame()" method, however I haven't coded this part yet).
Here is the code for this part:
namespace Quiz_for_bootcamp_project_1
{
    public class QuestionGameMethod1
    {
        public static void GameStart()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Please note: Write ALL answer in capital letters n/STARTING GAME...");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Console.WriteLine("Game starts in 3...");
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            Console.WriteLine("Game starts in 2...");
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            Console.WriteLine("Game starts in 1...");
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            Console.WriteLine("START!");

           Q1Present(QuestionSheet Q1, string uAInput, string answers);

        }
        public void Q1Present(QuestionSheet Q1, string uAInput, string answers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Q1.questions);
            UserAnswerIput();
            AnswerValidator(uAInput, answers);
            EndGame();
        }

        public static void EndGame() 
        { 
        Console.WriteLine($"game has ended! n/you got {userHighScore}!");
            if (userHighScore == 50) {
                Console.WriteLine("Great Job!"); 
                    }

            Console.WriteLine("if you want to try again, please restart the program");
            System.Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }   
}

The issue arises when I try to call the method "Q1Present" in the method "GameStart()", it yields a compilation error and says that the string parameters are either not valid or don't exist in the current context.
Thankyou in advance!

Q1Present(QuestionSheet Q1, string uAInput, string answers); - that's not how you call a method. That's closer to how you declare a method. Review how you call AnswerValidator for example, compared with how you're trying to call Q1Present.

Hey dude, I tried calling the method same as the other methods however it just yields the same error for answers and uAInput, for Q1 it says it's not null here.

You should take a step back and think what values you expect to be passing in. You don't have any variables called Q1, uAInput or answers, so how do you expect those arguments to be evaluated? (Maybe you need to revise how method calls work, and the difference between arguments and parameters.) If you had code of Console.WriteLine(uAInput); in GameStart(), what would you expect that to do?

There is a bunch of issues with the posted code. I would suggest starting with the simplest possible game, i.e. write everything in Main(), make sure it compiles and runs, and then start moving things to classes and methods, making sure it still compiles after ever change.

The following may be of interest: Methods (C# Programming Guide)

Why do you say the game is starting in 3...2...1, but have a 3 second delay in between each? There's no need for methods AddPoints and RemovePoints since they're both only called from a single method. It also makes your code more difficult to follow/read.
